# Mouse Wheel / Scroll event in React element without overflow (picture zoom)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is it possible to register onScroll event on a react element which does not have scrollbar / overflow ?

I wish to create zoom on a picture with mouse wheel scrolling.
I tried

```
<div style={{position: "relative", width: "100%", height:"100%"}} onScroll={ () => console.log("TEST")}>
```

this wont fire event, neither will onWheel. If I change event to onClick everything works.

I know it's possbile, because there is a React components which make it work, I tried react wheel handler and it works. But how do they make it register mouse wheel events when there is no overflow or scrollbars?

EDIT:

I got it to work when I manually added eventlistener to componentDidMount, this is my current component. Is there a way I could make synthetic event onWheel work? I tried to add onWheel to div's and img but it wont fire.

```
class Zoom extends Component {
    state = {
      size: 20,      
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll, true);
    }
    
    handleScroll = e => {
        e.preventDefault();  
        console.log(e)
        if (e.deltaY > 0 && this.state.size < 50) {
            this.setState({size: this.state.size + 1})
        } else if (e.deltaY < 0 && this.state.size > 20) {
            this.setState({size: this.state.size - 1})
        }       
      }
 
    render = () =>

    <div className="livetods-product-image-container" style={{
        top: openAsModal() ? '25%' : '20%',
        left: openAsModal() ? '30%' : '',
        right: openAsModal() ? '30%' : '',
        width: this.state.size + "%"        
    }}>

    <div className="livetods-product-image-button-container" >
                <div></div>             
                <h6 className="livetods-product-image-name">{this.props.name}</h6>
                <span className="livetods-modal-header-close-button" onClick={e => this.props.hideImage()}>&times;</span>   

    </div>

    <div style={{position: "relative", width: "100%", height:"100%"}}>

        <div style={{position: "absolute", padding: "5px"}}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearchPlus} color={'red'} style={{ width: '20px', height: '20px', pointerEvents:"none"}}/>
        </div>
        
            <img src={this.props.src} style={{borderRadius: "5px"}}/>      
       
    </div>

</div>
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onWheel` [event and its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386897/image-zoom-with-mouse-wheel-in-react) instead of `onScroll` to achieve the same result.

`onScroll` event no longer [bubbles up](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#ui-events) in react. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386897/image-zoom-with-mouse-wheel-in-react) is pretty similar.

`onWheel` works for both trackpad scrolling as well as mouse wheel scrolling.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-night-7z4yd?file=/src/App.js) is a simple example that shows `onWheel` working with your provided code sample.

UPDATE:

I have changed the codesanbox example to reflect your class component. `onWheel` works in it too now. The issue you could be facing earlier was a warning like this one:

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `isPropagationStopped` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html for more information.
```

The [workaround](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html) to which is adding `e.persist()` to your onScroll function, as shown in my example.

Comment: It still didnt work for me, I did get it to fire when I manually added eventlistener like so
componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll, true);
    }

Comment: If needed, you could edit the question and share the whole component where you are trying to implement it, and we could help you set the listener up from within React's synthetic events for your class component. Otherwise, you could just mark/upvote my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer! I updated original post with component code. It is working now with manually adding event listener. It would be great if I could make synthetic event work.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Hope this solves your issue.