# How to get an image to zoom out on wheel event in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, state, styled-components

I am trying to recreate the image zoom out effect like the one on the mrpops.ua  website. I have tried alot of different ways to recreate it but I am unable to do it can anyone give me some tips on how they would try to recreate it.

On wheel event increase counter for each wheel. Then switch case evaluates the different counter value and adds the animation of scaling the image down or up based on the count. If i scroll down count +1 and up count -1. Switch case 1: headerImg.style.animation = 'scaleDown 2s ease forwards'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image zoom with mouse wheel in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386897/image-zoom-with-mouse-wheel-in-react)

Comment: Hi I can see that the idea might be similar but not exactly what I was looking for. https://mrpops.ua/en   If someone can check the website the animation i want to recreate is the one that happens when you start scrolling the page all I am looking for is an idea of what to use in react to recreate it

Comment: It is the same ideea. The site you mentioned is also using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d . If you provide a code sanbox  with a similar structure I can help you with the effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.